# Checked Check Progress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: Here]

As you can see above, I have the data I pulled from the database and these are the radio inputs.

Each one has unique database ids and I want to check here with jquery.

For example, if the phone does not select one of the 16GB or 32GB options, I want to give a warning. Since the data coming here comes with a loop, the same thing will enter the loop.

If it is selected, I want to get the values in it.

I would be glad if you could help me.

```html
<form action="" type="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div id="form_step_1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="talepler mb-3">
          <H4>GB</H4>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3 titles">
              <input class="inputs" type="radio" id="1" name="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">16 GB</label>
              <input class="inputs" type="radio" id="2" name="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">32 GB</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <H4>DİSPLAY</H4>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3 titles">
              <input class="inputs" type="radio" id="3" name="2">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">durable</label>
              <input class="inputs" type="radio" id="4" name="2">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">broken</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="gonder">Gönder</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please do not post PHP in a question if it is only about jQuery. Also why are you looping a style? That is not ok

Comment: `if the phone does not select the memory partition` what does that mean? Remember we do NOT know your application

Comment: I arranged @mplungjan

Comment: But please click [edit], then click the [`[<>]` snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and make a [mcve] without PHP

Comment: I can't add php data?

Comment: We want a RUNNABLE HTML file with jQuery and CSS only. UNLESS your problem is related to the PHP. You just want to check the boxes are checked at run time NO?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want and if it is selected I want to get the id of that element

Comment: Your question is about js/jquery, not about php, so your snippet should include everything needed to *demonstrate* the issue / allow us to work with it to provide you a suitable answer.  For that, please include the *rendered* html and any relevant js/css - not the server-side code.

Comment: I added as you requested. @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the checked radios

I must suggest you give them better names and IDs

Note I gave the form an ID and removed the return false from the onsubmit

If you want to submit if ok, then my code will work

If you want to ajax the result, move the
e.preventDefault() to the top of the submit event handler

In this update I run over every title and look in the next div for radios.
You can add other elements to each

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/L7nhjo10/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myTable").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // comment this to submit when ok
    let errors = [],
      ids = [];
    $(".row h4").each(function() {
      let title = $(this).text(),
        $container = $(this).closest("div"), // parent
        $rads = $container.find("[type=radio]");
      if ($rads.length > 0) {
        let $chosen = $container.find("[type=radio]:checked");
        if ($chosen.length === 0) errors.push(title);
        else ids.push($chosen.attr("id"));
      }
    })
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Please choose " + errors.join(", "));
    } else console.log(ids);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myTable" action="" type="POST" onsubmit="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; return false;">
  <div id="form_step_1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="talepler mb-3">
          <h4>Telefon Hafızası Seçin</h4>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <input style="display: none" class="inputs" type="radio" id="1" name="1" value="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="1">16GB</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <input style="display: none" class="inputs" type="radio" id="2" name="1" value="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="2">32GB</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="talepler mb-3">
          <h4>Ekran Durumu Seçin</h4>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <input style="display: none" class="inputs" type="radio" id="3" name="2" value="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="3">Sağlam</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
              <input style="display: none" class="inputs" type="radio" id="4" name="2" value="1">
              <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;" for="4">Kırık</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="gonder">Gönder</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Also remove `onsubmit="return false"`

Comment: Solved. I told you I expected the container of BOTH radios to be the next sibling of the h4, but it is not. See update

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much bro. Good luck with your work. I'm so sorry if I was busy. Let me know if there's anything I can help with.

Comment: You are welcome, This is why we need rendered HTML and not PHP in questions about client code :)

Comment: You're right. Is there a place where I can reach you if you want to help?

Comment: In my profile...

Comment: feel free to remove all the comments here. There are so many

Answer (score 0):

i will make it simple for you !

add a class to the inputs for exemple : `storage` or `space`

preview :

```
<div class="row mb-3" style="display: inline-block">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3 titles">
          <input class="inputs storage" type="radio" id="1" name="1">
          <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">16 GB</label>
          <input class="inputs storage" type="radio" id="2" name="1">
          <label class="btn btn-pill" style="display: inline-block;">32 GB</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and then by jquery you can detect selected one:

```
$('.storage').on('change',function(){
    let selected  = $('.storage:checked');
    console.log(selected.val());
})
```

and for other inputs the same process

add new class to them exemple : `phone-status` or somthing else

and keep going

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes this works but when I select multiple the data is not coming. It will be more than 1 because data. All will be under different category and I need to pull id by categories. For example I chose 16GB and broken. I need to be able to get both these 2 values.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I want. Yes, I can pull the data, there is no problem here, it's fine. But I need to be able to pull other data as well. So I should be able to get the ids of both "16GB" and "broken" data. Also, the categories of these variables will multiply, and in some of them I will ask for the battery states. That's why I need to be able to pull the data from all the inputs I choose and I need to be able to assign it to the variable.